# HTML 5 Button in center

Tags: html, center

[my html button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6JRD.png)
Can you please guide me that how can i the button in the center of page in this situation.

Comment: <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">    
        <div class="col-md-12">  
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#about"><center> <button class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>
    <span>Learn More>>></span>
</button></center>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: This is my code

Comment: you may want to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39336437/edit) your question and add the details there instead of commenting them...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style for your a class.

```
.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```